# Redirection with Header(Location:) is not working when image is uploaded with dropjoneJS

Tags: php, dropzone.js

In my form, I am using dropzoneJS. I am trying to redirect user upon successful submission of user data and image in my database. Here is how I am trying to do it.
My form -

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
$userID = addUser() //This function create new user and return user id
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    //I have function here which will submit user images in a directory an create image path in DB table
    }
HEADER('LOCATION: view.php?id='.$userID);//User redirected to their profile page
}//If ends
```

Form begins:-

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" class="dropzone form-horizontal" id="my-awesome-dropzone"  method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type blah.. blah..>
<input type blah.. blan..>
<!-- DropzoneJS div -->
<div class="dropzone-previews form-group" style="height: 350px;"></div>
  <div class="fallback col-xs-3">
     <input name="file" class="input-file form-control "type="file" multiple/>
  </div>
<button type="submit" id="submit-all" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then DropzoneJS Settings

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
autoProcessQueue: false,
blah.. blah
blah.. blah

init: function() {
   var myDropzone = this;
   $("#submit-all").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
      if (myDropzone.files.length) {
        myDropzone.processQueue(); // upload files and submit the form
        } else {
        $('#my-awesome-dropzone').submit(); // submit the form
       }
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

Now, When user fills and submit the form (without images in dropzone field), the user data gets submitted in my database and user is successfully redirected their profile page (mywebsite.com/view.php?id=1). This is fine.

BUT problem is -
 When user fills and submit the form (with images in dropzone field), the user data and images both gets submitted in my database successfully as desired BUT redirection is not happening. This is not fine. why redirection is not happening?

Please suggest where is the wrong.

Answer (score 0):

there may be a syntax error. Try this:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
$userID = addUser(); //This function create new user and return user id
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    //I have function here which will submit user images in a directory an create image path in DB table
    }
header('Location: view.php?id='.$userID);//User redirected to their profile page
}//If ends
```

the second way to redirect:

```
header('Refresh: 5; URL='view.php?id='.$userID);
```

The third way to redirect:

```
<?php echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; url='view.php?id='.$userID.'">';?>
```

the fourth way to redirect:

```
<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){location.replace("view.php?id='.$userID.'");}, 5000);</script>';?>
```

Comment: I also tried this - 
`//Refresh page when all images are uploaded
 myDropzone.on("complete", function (file) {
         if (myDropzone.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
     var userid = "<?php $userID; ?>";
        window.location.replace("/view.php?id="+ userid);
        }
      });`


Now page is redirecting but userid is not getting its value, hence error page.
I tried - var userid = "<?php echo $userID; ?>"; but this makes drag-n-drop image field to stop working

Comment: try this variant:    windows.location.replace('view.php?id=<?php echo $userID; ?>' ) ;

Comment: Not working. Whenever I am adding the word `echo`, the dropzone field stop working. I think it is breaking js code. Without `echo` for e.g. `<?php $userID; ?>` is working but userID is not getting its value. I have tried every means.. double quote.. single quote.. with..without semicolon. This is important part of my small project. help will be highly appreciated.